# JQuery Sort Divs by child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html

I have the following list of divs and I'd like to be able to sort them using Javascript / JQuery.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="genre">Classical</div>
    <div class="name">Alpha</div>
    <div class="location">London</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="genre">Blues</div>
    <div class="name">Bravo</div>
    <div class="location">New York</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="genre">Pop</div>
    <div class="name">Charlie</div>
    <div class="location">Paris</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
<a href="">Sort by Genre</a>
<a href="">Sort by Name</a>
<a href="">Sort by Location</a>
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to sort the items by their Genre/Name/Location alphabetically.

Example: If Sort by Genre was clicked, it would sort the items in 0-9 A-Z by Genre.

If any of you have any tips it would greatly be appreciated.

Cheers :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make a little change to html like following:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="item">
    <div class="genre">Classical</div>
    <div class="name">Alpha</div>
    <div class="location">London</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="genre">Blues</div>
    <div class="name">Bravo</div>
    <div class="location">New York</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="genre">Pop</div>
    <div class="name">Charlie</div>
    <div class="location">Paris</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<a href="" id="genre">Sort by Genre</a>
<a href="" id="name">Sort by Name</a>
<a href="" id="location">Sort by Location</a>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
function sorting(tag) {
    var items = $('div.item').sort(function(a, b) {
        var txt1 = $.trim($('div.' + tag, a).text()),
            txt2 = $.trim($('div.' + tag, b).text());
        if (txt1 > txt2) return 1;
        else return -1;
    });
    return items;
}
$('.buttons a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#container').html(sorting(this.id));
});
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/81/)**

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this would be my pure JS solution.

First, we should wrap your `<div>`s into a larger container.

```
<div id = "wrapper">
   <div id = "item">...</div>
   <div id = "item">...</div>
   <div id = "item">...</div> 
</div>
```

Now, let's define a constant - which property do you want to sort it by? (this will probably be a function parameter later in your code).

```
var propName = "genre";
```

Let's get all the `<div>`s and put them in an array.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
var itemsArray = new Array();
```

Let us sort them lexicographically according to the text of the selected property.

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    itemsArray.push(items[i]);

itemsArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aProp = a.getElementsByClassName(propName)[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var bProp = b.getElementsByClassName(propName)[0] .firstChild.nodeValue;

    if (aProp < bProp)
        return -1;
    else if (aProp > bProp)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
});
```

Let us construct a document fragment consisting of the sorted `<div>`s.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++)
    fragment.appendChild(itemsArray[i].clone());
```

Finally, let us clear the contents of the `<div id = "wrapper">` and replace it with the document fragment.

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(fragment);
```

Also, note that `document.getElementsByClassName` does not work in IE<9, but I was now really lazy to cope with that issue.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nNXr4/

Answer (score 0):

Check this beast:

```
 function sortByCreatedOnAsc(a,b){
     return $(a).find('.created_on').text() > $(b).find('.created_on').text();
 }

 function sortByCreatedOnDesc(a,b){
    return $(a).find('.created_on').text() < $(b).find('.created_on').text();
 }

 function reorderEl(el){
     var container = $('#tasks');
     container.html('');
     el.each(function(){
         $(this).appendTo(container);
     });
 }

 $('#created_on').click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("asc")){
     reorderEl($('.task').sort(sortByCreatedOnDesc));
     $(this).removeClass("asc");
     $(this).addClass("desc");
   } else {
     reorderEl($('.task').sort(sortByCreatedOnAsc));
     $(this).removeClass("desc");
     $(this).addClass("asc");
   }
   return false;
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jKJc3/116/